# How to force add a route in linux

Tags: linux, routing

If I try to add a route with `route add dest X.X.X.X mask 255.255.252.0 gw X.X.X.X` I get `dest: Unknown host` message.  Nothing changes even if I add the `-n` switch, which I believe should prevent `route` from trying to interpret ip addresses as host names.  Regardless of the fact if the route is actually valid or not some proprietary software, that I need to work, tries this command and exits with failure.  Is it possible to “force” add a route without any checks/host name resolving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that the literal hostname `dest` is an unknown host.  `dest` is not a valid parameter for the `route` command.  If you can't change the software to call `route` differently, you'll have to do something like replacing `route` with a script that calls the real `route` with correct arguments.

Comment: The problem is that `dest` is actually an ipv4 address and it looks fine to me, I have no idea why `route` would not treat it as such.

Comment: It's not complaining about the IP address, it is complaining about the literal string `dest`.

Answer (score 0):

I take it that you want to add a host route like this:

```
route add -host X.X.X.X mask 255.255.252.0 gw X.X.X.X
```